# Cumulative percentage per column of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, cumulative-sum

I have a data.frame made up of daily temperatures per julian day for a number of stations.

Minimal reproducible example data.frame:

```
TemperatureData <- data.frame(
    Julian_Day = 1:365,
    Station_1 = c(rnorm(1:365, mean=10, sd=2)),
    Station_2 = c(rnorm(1:365, mean=10, sd=2)),
    Station_3 = c(rnorm(1:365, mean=10, sd=2))
)
```

I would like to determine the julian day on which each station exceeds a stated percentage of the total cumulative value, and for an output stating the julian day when this cumulative value threshold is reached for each station.

For example, say Station 1 has a total value of 4000, and after 180 julian days the cumulative value exceeds a set 50% threshold of the total value, and is repeated for each column of the data.frame (example of preferred output below).

```
Station_1   Station_2   Station_3
180         183         179
```

I assume this would utilise the cumsum function in some capacity, but not sure how to implement it. Can anyone help with this?

Let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base R solution:

```r
TemperatureData <- data.frame(
    Julian_Day = 1:365,
    Station_1 = c(rnorm(1:365, mean=10, sd=2)),
    Station_2 = c(rnorm(1:365, mean=10, sd=2)),
    Station_3 = c(rnorm(1:365, mean=10, sd=2))
)

TemperatureData$Station_1 <- cumsum(TemperatureData$Station_1) / sum(TemperatureData$Station_1)
TemperatureData$Station_2 <- cumsum(TemperatureData$Station_2) / sum(TemperatureData$Station_2)
TemperatureData$Station_3 <- cumsum(TemperatureData$Station_3) / sum(TemperatureData$Station_3)


results <- c(
  "Station 1" = TemperatureData$Julian_Day[TemperatureData$Station_1 >= .5][1],
  "Station 2" = TemperatureData$Julian_Day[TemperatureData$Station_2 >= .5][1],
  "Station 3" = TemperatureData$Julian_Day[TemperatureData$Station_3 >= .5][1]
)
results
#> Station 1 Station 2 Station 3 
#>       180       185       183
```

`tidyverse` solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
TemperatureData %>%
  summarize(across(matches("Station"), 
                   function(x) Julian_Day[cumsum(x) / sum(x) > .5][1]))
```

`data.table` solution:

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(TemperatureData)

TemperatureData[, lapply(.SD, function(x) Julian_Day[cumsum(x) / sum(x) > .5][1]), 
                .SDcols=patterns("Station")]
```

Comment: Hi Vincent, thanks very much for the rapid response! Just one quick question: I happen to have some _NaN_ values in my actual data.frame. So my output is returning _NA_ values for those stations, i've tried na.rm=T in the script, but no joy. Any thoughts?

Comment: AFAICT, the `cumsum` function does not have a `na.rm` argument. But if you don't want to increment on missing values, you could simply replace all `NA`s by 0 before using my functions. That way, the `cumsum` wouldn't increment on those observations, and you'll find the correct threshold.

Comment: Brilliant! That's working great now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: cool! feel free to click on the check mark to accept the answer that you end up using.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` way to do it. I figure there is a simpler method, and if I figure it out, I will post it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
TemperatureData %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Julian_Day, names_to = "Station") %>%
  group_by(Station) %>%
  arrange(Station, Julian_Day) %>%
  mutate(cumpct = cumsum(value) / sum(value)) %>%
  filter(cumpct >= 0.5) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = 1, names_from = Station, values_from = Julian_Day)

# A tibble: 1 x 3
  Station_1 Station_2 Station_3
      <int>     <int>     <int>
1       184       181       181
```